# Modular Arithmetic Congruence Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, coprime

If $c$ is odd and $cy$ $≡$ $4$ mod $n$, then $c$ is coprime to $n$.

Then it follows that $cy-4 = na$, so $cy-na = 4$. Then by Bezout's lemma, there exists integers $d$ and $w$ where $d=y$ and $e=-a$ such that $cd+na=4$, so the hcf($c,n$) = $4$, but this contradicts the fact that $c$ is odd. Contradiction, so $c$ and $n$ are coprime.

I feel like it isn't correct to apply Bezout's lemma like this. Help!

Comment: Your argument just shows that hcf$(c,n)$ divides $4$, not that it equals $4$.

Comment: @Arkady This is where I am confused. I thought that by Bezout's lemma it would equal 4,

Comment: Please state your version of Bezout's lemma in your post and then carefully see if what you are doing is applying it correctly.

Comment: Sorry I think I am being stupid. If we define the highest common factor of $c$ and $n$ to be $h$, then it must divide a linear combination of them, and so divided $2$. I can assume the hcf must be positive ? So $h$ $=1$ or $2$, but $c$ is odd so $h=1$.

Comment: Bezout’s Lemma - let $h$ = hcf ($a,b$), then there exist integers $c$ and $d$ such that $ac + bd = h$. I guess I applied it incorrectly as when using Bezout’s lemma you need to know the hcf and then write the equation, as it is if then statement

Comment: @Arkady Sorry meant h just be positive and divide 4 so 1,2 or 4, but since c is odd h = 1

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Given that :

- $cy \equiv 4 \pmod{n}$
- $c$ is odd.

To prove: $c$ is co-prime to $n$.

Without loss of generality, $c$ is not equal to either $(1)$ or $(-1)$. 
For example, if $c = 1$, you could take $y = 13, n = 9.$ 
If $c = -1$, you could take $y = -13, n = 17.$  
In both cases, you would have that $c,n$ are relatively prime.

From the premise, you know that $n$ divides $(cy - 4)$.

**Suppose** that $c$ is not co-prime to $n$.

Then, there exists some prime number $p$ such that $p$ divides $n$ and $p$ divides $c$.

Further, since $c$ is odd, you know that the prime number $p$ must be odd.

Since $n$ divides $(cy - 4)$, there exists some integer $a$ such that $an = cy - 4.$  Further, since $c$ is assumed to not equal $1$ or $-1$, and $c$ is odd, you know that $(cy)$ is not equal to $(4)$.

Therefore, $cy - 4$ is not equal to $(0)$.  Therefore, $a$ is not equal to $(0)$.

So, you have that

$cy - an = 4$ and that $p$, an odd prime, divides both $n$ and $c$.  Therefore, the odd prime $p$ divides $4$.  This yields a contradiction.

Since the contradiction was explicitly caused by the assumption that there exists some prime $p$ such that $p$ is a factor of both $c$ and $n$, this assumption must be false.

Therefore, $c$ and $n$ must be coprime.

Comment: can you check my corrected version in the comments. Is that a valid step and hence proof okay ?

Comment: @NikitaMazepin It is unclear to me that [Bezout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) can be used to solve the problem.  Perhaps it can, and I am just not seeing it.  There must exist integers $r,s$ such that $$ry + sn = 1 \implies 4ry + 4sn = 4 = cy - na \implies $$ $$y(4r - c) = n(-a - 4s).$$  It is unclear to me whether this helps solve the problem.  For one thing, you could have (for example) $$4r - c = 0 = -a - 4s.$$  So, while I could be mistaken, I don't immediately see any way that Bezout's Lemma solves the problem.

Comment: @NikitaMazepin In my opinion, the key to the problem is that you are supposed to leverage the combined facts that $c$ is odd and that $(4)$ has no odd prime factors.  Therefore, you are supposed to conclude that any prime factor of $c$ can not be a prime factor of $4$.  I have a hard time envisioning any way of using these facts other than the approach that I took.

Comment: Okay cool, so by definition $cy-4 = na$, so $cy-na = 4$. Define $h$ as the hcf($a,n$), so $h$ divides $cy-na$, and hence $h$ divides $4$. The highest common factor must be positive, so $1,2,4$, but since $c$ is odd, this means hcf = $1$, and so $c$ and $n$ are coprime ?

Comment: @NikitaMazepin Don't think in terms of (for example) highest common factor.  Instead, think in terms of prime numbers.  So, if $c$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, there exists some prime number $p$ such that $p$ divides both $c$ and $n$.  Thinking in terms of prime numbers, rather than *common factors* greatly simplifies the analysis.

Comment: is what I said in my previous comment though an incorrect proof ? If so, why?

Comment: @NikitaMazepin After thinking about it, the analysis in your previous comment, where you conclude that $h$ must be an element in $\{1,2,4\}$ seems valid to me.  Assuming that I am not overlooking anything, this implies that the entire approach represented by your previous comment is a good proof.